# Selenium-Python: Class containing link-text

Tags: python, css, selenium

I am using Python & Selenium to scrap the content of a certain webpage. Currently, I have the following problem: There are multiple div-classes with the same name, but each div-class has different content. I only need the information for one particular div-class. In the following example, I would need the information in the first "show_result"-class since there is the "**Important-Element**" within the link text:

```
<div class="show_result">
    <a href="?submitaction=showMoreid=77" title="Go-here">
    <span class="new">Important-Element</span></a>
    Other text, links, etc within the class...
</div>

<div class="show_result">
    <a href="?submitaction=showMoreid=78" title="Go-here">
    <span class="new">Not-Important-Element</span></a>
    Other text, links, etc within the class...
</div>

<div class="show_result">
    <a href="?submitaction=showMoreid=79" title="Go-here">
    <span class="new">Not-Important-Element</span></a>
    Other text, links, etc within the class...
</div>
```

With the following code I can get the "Important-Element" and its link:
`driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Important-Element')`. However, I also need the other information within the same div-class "show-result". How can I refer to the entire div-class that contains the Important-Element in the link text? `driver.find_elements_by_class_name('show_result')` does not work since I do not know in which of the div-classes the Important-Element is located.

Thanks,
Finn

**Edit / Update**: Ups, I found the solution on my own using xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'show_result') and contains(., 'Important-Element')]")
```

Comment: You can add it as answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you've found an answer but I believe it's wrong since you would also select the other nodes because Important-Element is still in Non-Important-Element.

Maybe it works for your specific case since that's not really the text you're after. But here are a few more answers:

1. `//div[@class='show_result' and starts-with(.,'Important-Element')]`
2. `//div[span[text()='Important-Element']]`
3. `//div[contains(span/text(),'Important-Element') and not(contains(span/text(),'Non'))]`

There are more ways to write this...

Comment: Thanks, you are actually correct. My solution worked in my case since the name for the elements were not "Important-Element" and "Not-Important-Element" etc. They had mutually exclusive names a la "Zebra", "Gorilla" etc. and, hence, my xpath-contains worked.

Answer (score 1):

Ups, i found the solution on my own via xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'show_result') and contains(., 'Important-Element')]")
```